# Unable to find and click checkbox using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I've looked at a few different answers to similar questions, but can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my specific situation.  I've gone through most of my script to get where I want, but the authorize checkbox just can't seem to be found.

And in Python pretty simply:

```
### Authorize
driver.find_element('name', "d_1559640796736").click()
```

With the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="d_1559640796736"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.120)
```

I've tried every other way to find the element (id, css, xpath), but it's possible my xpath is just wrong.  I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that it is a fieldset.  I admit my Python is much better than my html.

Snapshot of the HTML:

[image: html]

Comment: Do these checks first, if this is inside iframe or it is not visible?

Comment: No iframe seems to be in the code.  I had a similar issue earlier in my script where I had to switch to an iframe and was successful there. 

There is a hidden input above it, but I don't believe it has anything to do with the checkbox. Actually it could be.  Yup, it has the same name.

Answer (score 1):

The *classname* attribute values like *`d_1559640796736`*, *`h_1559640796736o1`* are dynamically generated and is bound to chage sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='Acknowledge'][name^='d_'][id^='d_'][id$='o1']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Acknowledge' and starts-with(@name, 'd_')][starts-with(@id, 'h_') and contains(@id, 'o1')][starts-with(@id, 'h_') and contains(@id, 'o1')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: The XPATH method worked perfectly.  Thanks!  I'll look into those locator strategies as many other find_element portions of my script use "name" or "id", with similar naming patterns.  It seems to work daily, but who knows for how long.

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath instead of finding it by name

```
//input[@type='checkbox'][1]
```

You can select one by it's index if there are multiple checkboxes present.